# non blocking Interlocked usage issue with Parallel (TPL)

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am confused about the accuracy of code in multi threading as some time I am getting wrong result.

Looks like it might fail. Below is the code.

```
public class MyKeyValue
{
    public double Key { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}

public class CollMyKeyValue : List<MyKeyValue>
{
    public void SumUpValues(CollMyKeyValue collection)
    {
        int count =0;
        Parallel.For(count, this.Count, 
        (i) => 
        {
            this[count].Value = this[count].Value + collection[count].Value;
            Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
        });  
    }
}
```

Assuming the keys are same in both collection.

I want add the values of one collection into another. Is it therad safe ?

I have not put the `this[count].Value = this[count].Value + collection[count].Value;` in thread safe block.

Comment: are you sure that you didn't mix up `count` and `i` ... currently your code doesn't make sense to me ...

Comment: This seems like an inefficient place to parallelize.  You can add your entire RAM's worth of doubles in about a second.  Adding the overhead of the task you might make marginal gains here, but there are probably better places in your application to look for gains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the interlocked increment :

```
public void SumUpValues(CollMyKeyValue collection)
{
    //int count =0;
    Parallel.For(0, this.Count, 
        (i) => 
            {
                this[i].Value = this[i].Value + collection[i].Value;
                //Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
            });  
}
```

Your version is altering the index variable inside the loop.  The `For` loop does this automatically; in the parallel version each thread gets an `i` (or set of `i`) to do, so incrementing in the loop makes no sense.

Comment: i am not sure if it gives a compiler error, and i doubt so. it is just the parameter of the `.For`-method, which by the nature of int, is only per value, and not reused somehwere else ..

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what you're trying to do. But I guess you mean this.

```
public void SumUpValues(CollMyKeyValue collection)
{
    Parallel.For(0, this.Count, (i) =>
    {
        this[i].Value += collection[i].Value;
    });
}
```

First parameter says the `Parallel.For` where to start, altering that makes no sense. You get `i` as the parameter to the loop body which will tell you which iteration you're in.